# rust-analyzer can you autoinject variable type declarations?

Tags: rust, code-injection, rust-analyzer

Is it possible to run rust analyzer to not just display but outright inject variable types on variable declarations?

Say in this case

[image]

The linter is displaying the type, I would like it to inject the characters instead of just showing them.

Comment: I don't think there's something you can do. Rust is designed with inference in mind.

Comment: Rust analyzer is displaying the characters right there, why can;t I run it from the terminalk and get it to inject those characters instead of them just showing as phantoms?

Comment: Because nobody has implemented that. rust-analyzer has an (unstable) API, so I think you can implement that yourself. Look at how it implements the `analysis-stats` command.

Comment: Decided to delete my answer because I learned about `rust-analyzer ssr` (which does something related but isn't strong enough for this). In any case, the easiest way of getting this is probably to get an editor with [code actions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6F7VK.gif) and macro the heck out of it.